How to XOR shapes with CSS only?
In the example below, the two XORed bars do not completely cancel out when perfectly aligned. You can see their outline.
How to make the outline disappear, which is what a correct XOR should do?


.container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    filter: invert(100%);
    position: relative;
    height: 100vh;
}

.a {
    position: absolute;
    width: 250px;
    height: 50px;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    background: white;
}

.b {
    position: absolute;
    width: 250px;
    height: 50px;
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
    mix-blend-mode: difference;
    background: white;
    animation: spin 1s infinite alternate;
}

@keyframes spin {
  0% { transform: rotate(30deg) }
  50% { transform: rotate(45deg) }
  100% { transform: rotate(60deg) }
}
<div class="container">
  <div class="a"></div>
  <div class="b"></div>
 </div>




Note that without the animation, there is no outline: https://jsfiddle.net/593u8tjx/ (at least on Chrome Version 124.0.6367.208 (Official Build) (64-bit) on Windows 10.

@HereticMonkey I see it on 125.0.6422.112 and 113 (Official Build) (64-bit) Win11

For me the outline exists when transform:rotate is applied on both element. If both initial rotate are moved to the container, the outline disappeared disregarding the animation.

@j08691 I just got updated to 125.0.6422.113 and see it now.

@SyndRain https://jsfiddle.net/vtmLj90p/ Yep, it you remove the transformation, the outline goes away. Probably an artifact from the transformation...

Adding black outlines on both div appears to fix the problem for me. (At least on Chrome, Edge, and FF)
outline: 2px solid black;
outline-offset:-1px;

Note that I've added an animation delay to show the weird border disappeared.


.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  filter: invert(100%);
  position: relative;
  height: 100vh;
}

.a {
  position: absolute;
  width: 250px;
  height: 50px;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  background: white;
  outline: 2px solid black;
  outline-offset: -1px;
}

.b {
  position: absolute;
  width: 250px;
  height: 50px;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  mix-blend-mode: difference;
  background: white;
  outline: 2px solid black;
  outline-offset: -1px;
  animation: spin 1s infinite alternate;
  animation-delay: 1s;
}

@keyframes spin {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(30deg)
  }
  50% {
    transform: rotate(45deg)
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(60deg)
  }
}
<div class="container">
  <div class="a"></div>
  <div class="b"></div>
</div>




This must be qualified as a workaround, not as a full answer. It does "make the outline disappear" as requested in the question, albeit not in the same configuration.
If you remove the transformation, as noticed by @SyndRain, the XOR works, even in animation (modified to show the fully XORed stated longer):


.container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    filter: invert(100%);
    position: relative;
    height: 100vh;
}

.a {
    position: absolute;
    width: 250px;
    height: 50px;
    background: white;
}

.b {
    position: absolute;
    width: 250px;
    height: 50px;
    mix-blend-mode: difference;
    background: white;
    animation: spin 2s infinite alternate;
}

@keyframes spin {
  0% { transform: rotate(0deg) }
  50% { transform: rotate(0deg) }
  100% { transform: rotate(45deg) }
}
<div class="container">
  <div class="a"></div>
  <div class="b"></div>
 </div>




There is a black line that looks like border-bottom: 1px solid black in Brave on desktop.
